# Giraph build for Hadoop Yarn profile fails with org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException

Tags: maven, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, giraph

I am trying to build Giraph for Hadoop 2.7.1 using the Yarn profile. I am getting a `TransferFailedException` for resource at: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-8/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-8.jar.

The resource is available through the browser though. The build command I'm executing is:

```
mvn -e -DskipTests -Dhadoop.version=2.7.1 -Phadoop_yarn clean install
```

My setup is :

- Java Version   :  1.7.0_79
- Hadoop Version :  2.7.1
- Giraph Version :  1.1.0
- Maven Version  :  3.0.5

The build error stack trace is as follows:

```
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10:check (default) @ giraph-core ---
[INFO] Starting audit...
Audit done.

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- apache-rat-plugin:0.8:check (default) @ giraph-core ---
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-8/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-8.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Giraph Parent .............................. SUCCESS [5.417s]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Core ................................ FAILURE [40.194s]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Examples ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Distribution ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 46.202s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 07 12:00:24 PDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 60M/638M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.8:check (default) on project giraph-core: Execution default of goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.8:check failed: Plugin org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.0-alpha-8 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-8/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-8.jar. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Unavailable. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.8:check (default) on project giraph-core: Execution default of goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.8:check failed: Plugin org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.0-alpha-8 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-8/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-8.jar. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Unavailable.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.8:check failed: Plugin org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.0-alpha-8 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-8/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-8.jar. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Unavailable.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.0-alpha-8 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-8/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-8.jar. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Unavailable.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:78)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.0-alpha-8 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-8/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-8.jar. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Unavailable.
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:358)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:207)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.0-alpha-8 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-8/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-8.jar. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Unavailable.
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:939)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-8/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-8.jar. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Unavailable.
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:945)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
    ... 4 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :giraph-core
```

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: @MohammadGhazanfar, It worked for me back then by using sudo for executing the command.

Comment: I'll try that ! Thank you !